# What is the meaning of Confidence Intervals regarding Hold Out samples?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, out-of-sample

Let's say you have a regression model that estimates GDP.  Your model has a Standard Error of 1%.  So, you can readily build Confidence Intervals around your regressed estimates.  Your 95% CI will be + or - ~2% around your model estimates.  You look at the Learning sample of your model, and you observe that about 1 in 20 of your actual observations fall outside your 95% CI.  You conclude that's about right as it is what you would expect from such a specified 95% CI.  Now, you look at a Hold Out sample of 10 observations.  And, you observe that 3 out of your 10 observations fall outside this CI.  You use BINOMDIST() function, and you find out there is only a 1% probability that 3 out of 10 observations would be outside the 95% CI.  What can you conclude from that?  Is your model truly mispecified? Or are such built CIs using the Learning sample of the model not that applicable on the Hold Out sample?  They give you some indication of the model fit and predictive power, but absent any real statistical grounding, if that is the case?  Also, how do you interpret such CIs throughout the Hold Out sample?  The first observation should be pretty close from within the CIs.  But, as you go out in the 9th and 10th observations, you should have more tolerance for outliers being outside the 95% CI.  How do you do that?

Comment: Look at Chow tests, they evaluate the forecast errors in relation to the confidence intervals  from training samples.

Comment: The Chow test deals with structural breaks in your data.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test.  That's very different.  You may be talking of a different Chow test.  Would you have a relevant link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this paper](http://www.federalreserve.gov/Pubs/Ifdp/1991/412/ifdp412.pdf) on p.4 for Chow test setup: Ericsson, Neil R. "Parameter constancy, mean square forecast errors, and measuring forecast performance: An exposition, extensions, and illustration." Journal of policy modeling 14.4 (1992): 465-495.

The idea's that you estimate the model on the training sample, then produce one step ahead forecasts in the holdout sample. The mean squared forecast error is compared to the error variance from the estimated model. Your $H_0$ is that if the model holds, then it holds in entire holdout sample. Whether it's the first period or 9th doesn't matter. If you specify your data generation process as $y_t=f(x_t,y_{s<t})+\varepsilon_t$, where $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$ then you're implying that $\sigma$ is not time varying. Hence, conditional on $y_{s<t}$ the error variance must be constant.

You can go after dynamic multi-step forecasts: $y_t=f(x_t,y_0)+\varepsilon_t$, where $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_t)$. Here the error variance is time-dependent. Something like a random walk would be a good example. In this case error variance at 9th observation in the holdout is going to differnet (often larger) than in the 1st. This may sound like a better idea, but there are considerations against it, see e.g. p.5 in [this paper](http://www.nuffield.ox.ac.uk/Users/Hendry/Papers/MPCDFHcho.pdf): Clements, Michael P., and David F. Hendry. "Evaluating a model by forecast performance*." Oxford Bulletin of Economics and Statistics 67.s1 (2005): 931-956.

That paper is actually an interesting survey of forecast evaluation approaches in econometrics. Ericsson would argue that you don't compare 9-step forecast error to 1-step ahead forecast error. That these are different animals, and they tell you different things about your model. You would compare 9-step dynamic forecast to the same of a different model, for instance.

Comment: Aksakal, thank you so much, this is an extremely informative answer.  I will read and digest all this information tonight.